# Knuth–Morris–Pratt string match algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, strings

The Knuth–Morris–Pratt string search algorithm is described in the paper [*Fast Pattern Matching in Strings*](http://www.cin.br/~paguso/courses/if767/bib/KMP_1977.pdf) (*SIAM J. Computing* vol. 6 no. 2, June 1977). The initial step of the algorithm is to compute the *next* table, defined as follows:

> The pattern-matching process will run efficiently if we have an auxiliary table that tells us exactly how far to slide the pattern, when we detect a mismatch at its `j`th character `pattern[j]`. Let `next[j]` be the character position in the pattern which should be checked next after such a mismatch, so that we are sliding the pattern `j − next[j]` places relative to the text.

The authors give the example of the pattern `abcabcacab`. If there is a mismatch at `j`=7:

```
abcabcacab
abcabca?
```

Then the pattern should be moved 3 places to the right and matching should continue with the 4th character of the pattern:

```
   abcabcacab
abcabca?
```

so `next[7] = 4`. In some cases we know we can skip the mismatched character entirely, for example if there is a mismatch at `j=3`:

```
abcabcacab
abc?
```

then the search should continue from the character after the mismatch:

```
    abcabcacab
abc?
```

These special cases are indicated by `next[j] = −1`.

(If you're reading the paper, note that the authors use indexes starting at 1 as in Fortran, but the Python convention is to use indexes starting at 0, so that's what I'm giving here.)

This is the code that computes the *next* table. Please review.

```
def findPattern(pattern):

    j = -1
    next = [-1] * len(pattern)
    i = 0 # next[0] is always -1, by KMP definition

    while (i+1 < len(pattern)):
        if (j == -1) or (pattern[j] == pattern[i]):
            i += 1
            j += 1
            if pattern[i] != pattern[j]:
                next[i] = j
            else:
                next[i] = next[j]
        else:
            j = next[j]

    return next

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print findPattern("aaaab")
    print findPattern("abaabc")
```

Output:

```
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 3]
[-1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 2]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  What kind of patterns are you expecting to find?

Comment: @holroy, good question. Posted output and I think they should be expected? If you have found any functional issues, appreciate to share with me. :)

Comment: Could you please write with words, what that output means? It's still a little unclear, and that makes it harder to provide a good review.

Comment: The algorithm linked is for detecting strings, but you said you're using it to create patterns? It's very hard to follow what your code is for in its current state.

Comment: I think that this is supposed to be the "table-building" part of the Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm. However, it doesn't build the same table as the algorithm given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm), where it says the word `ABCDABCD` becomes the table [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3], but `findPattern("ABCDABCD")` returns [-1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0]. So either there's a bug in your code, or you are implementing some other table-building function and need to explain in more detail.

Comment: @holroy, what do you mean write with words? Do you mean how to match pattern to a real string?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan, the code I posted is for creating pattern, so that string match could use the pattern for matching in the future. If you found any functional bugs, appreciate for point out. :)

Comment: @GarethRees, nice catch. I think the result " [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]" for "ABCDABCD" is not correct, since the 4th element is 0 (I count from 0, not from 1), which means if the 2nd A is not matched, we will begin to match with 0-th element A again, I think since A is not matched, we should not compare with A again, so my output for 4-th element is -1. If anything wrong in understanding, please feel free to correct me. Thanks. :)

Comment: @holroy, yes, you are correct. My code is for generating pattern only. The output means if there is a non-match for the related character in the pattern, what is the next character should be used to compare to. -1 means no possible match at current character. Any advice or insights are appreciated for any functional issues for my code. Thanks. :)

Comment: @GarethRees, if you have any comments for my reply, it will be great. :)

Comment: I have been reading the original [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://www.cin.br/~paguso/courses/if767/bib/KMP_1977.pdf) paper, from which I have learned that the Wikipedia article is seriously misleading — the algorithm it describes is not the same as the one in the KMP paper. The `T` table described in the Wikipedia article is the same as the `f` table in KMP — but the `f` table is just a step in the actual construction of the `next` table, which is what the KMP algorithm actually uses. So ignore what I said about failing to match the Wikipedia algorithm.

Comment: I revised the question to explain in detail what it computes, and I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @GarethRees, awesome! So, findPattern("ABCDABCD") returns [-1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0] is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @GarethRees, awesome, I totally agree all of your comments and will adopt your new style, just wondering in my original code, if any functional issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Review

1. There's no docstring.
2. There's no need for parentheses around conditions (Python is not C), so instead of:

   ```
   while (i+1 < len(pattern)):
   ```

   you can write:

   ```
   while i+1 < len(pattern):
   ```
3. The loop `while i+1 < len(pattern)` calls the `len` function on each iteration, even though `pattern` has not changed. You could avoid this wasted call by caching `len(pattern)` in a local variable.
4. The `or` operator has lower precedence than comparison operators, so instead of:

   ```
   if (j == -1) or (pattern[j] == pattern[i]):
   ```

   you can omit the parentheses:

   ```
   if j == -1 or pattern[j] == pattern[i]:
   ```
5. When there's a choice about whether to test for equality or inequality, then I think it's usually clearer to test for equality, so I would write `if pattern[i] == pattern[j]` instead of `if pattern[i] != pattern[j]`.
6. There's a small inefficiency in your code. If the test `j == -1 or pattern[j] == pattern[i]` passes then you set `j = next[j]` and go round the `while` loop again. But the condition on the `while` loop is a condition on `i`, which has not changed, so you waste the test. It is better to go straight to the test on `j`, like this:

   ```
   m = len(pattern)
   while i + 1 < m
       while j > -1 and pattern[i] != pattern[j]:
           j = next[j]
       i += 1
       j += 1
       if pattern[i] == pattern[j]:
           next[i] = next[j]
       else:
           next[i] = j
   ```
7. After making this change, `i` always increases by 1 on each iteration of the main loop, so we could use a `for` loop instead to make this clear.

#### 2. Revised code

```
def kmp_table(pattern):
    """Compute the "next" table corresponding to pattern, for use in the
    Knuth-Morris-Pratt string search algorithm.

    """
    m = len(pattern)
    next = [-1] * m
    j = -1
    for i in range(1, m):
        while j > -1 and pattern[i-1] != pattern[j]:
            j = next[j]
        j += 1
        if pattern[i] != pattern[j]:
            next[i] = j
        else:
            next[i] = next[j]
    return next
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, accepted for your reply and appreciate for the learning. Wondering if any other functional bugs in your mind? For functional I mean the next[] is not generated correctly. :)

Comment: The logic looks identical to that given in KMP, and it gives the same results as the examples in the paper. I haven't checked it beyond that.

Comment: Thanks Gareth, as long as you did not find any bugs, I am confident. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help Gareth, mark your reply as an answer. Have a good weekend. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Effiiency time-complexity bug**

```
while (i+1 < len(pattern)):
```

`len(pattern)` is evaluated at each iteration, even if it remains constant, this makes your time complexity `n` times slower, where n is `len(pattern)`

Use a variable to fix the bug:

```
pattern_length = len(pattern)
```

And:

```
while (i + 1 < pattern_length):
```

Comment: Thanks Caridorc, accepted for your reply and appreciate for the learning. Wondering if any other functional bugs in your mind? For functional I mean the next[] is not generated correctly. :)

Comment: `len` is a constant time operation on strings and other builtin types, because each object stores its length.

Comment: @JanneKarila Good I will delete this answer